# New site created in subdomain, how to move it as a production site and not a subdomain anymore

Tags: dns, subdomain

We have a site `www.site.example` using IP address `192.0.2.89` and we have a newly designed website running from a test run subdomain `testrun.site.example` using IP address `192.0.2.21`.

Now the newly designed website is done. It has the same directory structure, we keep the URL intact, same location of images , but different design overall.

**Question:** if I change the DNS `A` record of `www.site.example` website to use 
the IP address of `testrun.site.com`(`192.0.2.21`) will my `www.site.example` use the new design from the testrun subdomain `testrun.site.example`?

Is this possible?

NOTE:

- Site is hosted with Apache
- The `testrun.site.example` and `site.example`is hosted from the same dedicated server

Comment: Much depends upon your set-up. Is the sub-domain hosted on the same server as your current website? Are you using Apache? What else can you tell us so that we can formulate a better answer for you. My first inclination would be to answer *not likely* but I do not have enough information to formulate an accurate answer yet. Can you edit your question with some details about how these sites are set up?

Comment: hi , yes its apache, and hosted from the same webhosting. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is on the exact same server, the IP should not matter. What will matter is the Apache setup. You probably only have to change the DocumentRoot directive of the `www.example.com` entry to use the same directory as the new website.

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/look-here-now
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this will work the way you imagine. I could be wrong.

I am assuming that both sites are on the same Apache server. I am also assuming that your sites are set up as `example.com` and *not* `www.example.com` and `testrun.example.com`. Most of the time, a site on Apache would set up as `example` and `example.com` would have an IP address assigned in the DNS. `www.example.com` would be a `CNAME` that points to `example.com`. I am working on this premise.

Generally Apache is assigned IP addresses and ports to listen to in the `ports.conf` file. Websites within Apache are not normally assigned IP addresses. You will have to check your configuration files. If this is the case, then Apache will take any packet in regardless of the IP address and process them the same.

Apache will take the request packet, examine the to address and try and match it to a website. It may still try and match any request sent to `example.com` or `www.example.com` to `example.com` and not to `testrun.example.com`. This is because the request packet will not be addressed to `testrun.example.com`.

Check your configuration files.

Your can find your Apache configuration files in `/etc/apache2/` or `/etc/local/apache2/`. Check the `ports.conf` file and you should see both IP addresses. You will find your site specific configuration files in `/sites-available/`. The file name format would be `domainname.tld.conf` and `sub-domain.domainname.tld.conf`. Check both files for the existence of your IP addresses.

If you do not see the IP addresses in the site configuration files, then I would say that I do not believe your idea will work. If you do, then I would say perhaps- try it.

If you can afford a short period of downtime, then you can experiment and try this scenario easily. Otherwise, if up time is critical, I would not mess around and simply deploy your new site over your old site only after two complete backups are completed that you are sure you can use to restore the site.

In fact, the other answer to change the directory should also work and could easily be backed out if you change your mind.